# JavaScript KeywordQuery Search {Today-30} not working

Tags: 2013, javascript, search, keywordquery

I have a kerywordquery in JS that is working but when i add {today-30} it does not.

This is working:

```
(RefinableStartDate<=Today AND RefinableEndDate>Today)
```

It does not when I add -30 days:

```
(RefinableStartDate<=Today AND RefinableEndDate>Today AND
RefinableStartDate>{Today-30})
```

Note: The 2nd line does actually work inside of a SP results source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because this is in JS i passed in the date -30 days in the correct format.

```
var date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate() - 30);
var dateString = date.toISOString().split('T')[0];

query = " (RefinableStartDate<=Today AND RefinableEndDate>Today AND RefinableStartDate>\"" + dateString + "\")";
```